# Find a file in the path without "which"?

Tags: bash, shell, path

I am (somehow) able to run a script:

```
$ assemble.sh file
... [output]
```

But `which` can't find it:

```
$ which assemble.sh
which: no assemble.sh in (/s/std/bin:/usr/afsws/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/stat/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:.
```

1. How is this possible?
2. How can I find where this file is?

I'm using bash.

Comment: Is `assemble.sh` in your current directory?

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but is it an alias (i.e. does assemble.sh show up when you type the command

`alias`

?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Great guess! It was my case for acme.sh (https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh). After install, acme.sh alias was created and I wondered how acme.sh is called despite not being in PATH var.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use this command:  `type assemble.sh`

It works in a variety of shells and shows only the first result.

Comment: Or just `type assemble.sh`, which is portable (and only shows the first match whereas `type -a` is a ksh/bash construct to show all matches).

Answer (score 8):

Or split the path, and use it in find - the first match should be the solution

```sh
find ${PATH//:/ } -maxdepth 1 -name assemble.sh -print -quit
```

`type` is of course more easy.

Comment: This is fairly useful. I didn't know I could split $PATH into its sub components and search each one with `find`

Comment: Didn't try but I guess this can break with spaces in components of PATH

Answer (score 4):

You may be using bash, but the syntax of the `which` output shows that you use the old `which` written in csh. The PATH shows up quoted by parentheses, and the directories in PATH have entries like `/opt/SUNWspro/bin` and `/usr/ccs/bin` which only make sense in Solaris. That's consistent: Solaris used the csh `which`.

Here's my guess: you've got one PATH for bash, and another for csh.  This might be a system problem.  As I recall, Solaris keeps /etc/profile and /etc/cshrc files for system-wide PATH setting. Those two initialization files might set different PATH variables for different shells.  Do "echo $PATH" under bash, and see if it agrees with what the `which` command prints out as a PATH string.

Answer (score 4):

```
command -v assemble.sh
```

Info

```
-v        print a description of COMMAND similar to the `type' builtin
```

Comment: Also would be useful if you want to find in a modified version of PATH
`ASSEMBLE=$(PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin command -v assemble.sh)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locate assemble.sh` to find the location of the file.

Comment: No, this shows the location of all (world-)readable files whose name contain `assemble.sh`, which is irrelevant here.

Comment: It is not irrelevant at all. Even if he had multiple files called like that `locate` would also give him the location of the one he wants. `assemble.sh` is not such a common filename, so he will likely find the file easily (which is what the OP requests).

Comment: Don't you have to `updatedb` before `locate` shows results?

Comment: Usually `updatedb` is run daily as a cron job, but yeah, you may have to force it if the file is very recent.