# What could cause which to not show something in the path?

Tags: path, aix, ksh

There is an executable in my path that I believe is a perl script.

```
>$scriptname
$outputofscript
```

but

```
>which $scriptname
which:  0652-141 There is no $scriptname in $path
```

and the path it prints is the same that `echo $PATH` gives (except space delimited rather than colon).

Running ksh again does not appear to change my path, but now the script is not found.

This is as a normal user running ksh on AIX 6.1 over telnet (yeah, I know).

Comment: Obvious comment, but check the script has executable permissions.

Comment: Does `whereis` work in both cases? If yes, `$PATH` is somehow changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `type $scriptname` told me that it was an alias. Apparently this prevented it from being found by which.

Comment: Oh right, I should have mentioned that too. See [that previous related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/find-a-file-in-the-path-without-which). `which` is an external command and doesn't see aliases or functions. Prefer `type` or (if available) `whence`.

Answer (score 0):

[`which` is a csh script on AIX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds6/which.htm), and [it might use a different path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/find-a-file-in-the-path-without-which). But that doesn't seem to be exactly your problem, since `which` prints the expected path.

Are you absolutely sure you didn't have a different path in the first `ksh` session? Running ksh again might have changed the `PATH` because it ran `~/.kshrc` or `$ENV`. (And just to be sure, does the script still exist, or could it simply have been deleted in the meantime?)

Comment: Positive that the script was not deleted - it worked again afterwards. `echo $PATH` produced the same output in the inner and outer ksh, but perhaps it's possible for that to be wrong or misleading?